# Can I operate ROS master on Windows and ROS client on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, window, ros

I am hoping to have a Robot Operating System (ROS) master running on Windows OS and a ROS client running on Linux OS. Following is my desired architecture.[image: Architecture]

Upon searching for this architecture, I found [win_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/win_ros) which runs ROS on windows. But I did not find a work which operate windows master ROS and linux client ROS.

So my question is, can I run ROS master on Windows and ROS client on Linux and communicate between them?

Answer (score 0):

An important note is that the `win_ros` package is currently EOL and shouldn't be used. That said, there isn't a current version of ROS1 which supports a Windows master and Linux nodes. Instead, you should be using [ROS2](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Installation.html), which is currently being updated and supports what you want.

Comment: Alternatively if ROS1 is needed one could use WSL2 on Windows

Comment: @Combinacijus I’ve gotten ROS1 to work on WSL. But from a completeness standpoint I would necessarily recommend it over something like docker. It runs a full Linux kernel and is 99% of the way there, but that last 1% can burn you if you start getting into the weeds